# dc-js disable selecting slices on click for pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm looking for bar chart *brushOn(false)* analog for pie chart.

This code also does not work for me:

```
  chart.renderlet (_chart) ->
    _chart.selectAll(".pie-slice").on "click", (d) ->
      _chart.filter null
```

My dc-js version is 2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dc-js-user-group/Fxg4vykNSqI/hgdj2PEomHsJ :

```
pieChart.filter = function() {};
```

I tried this out at http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/3chM6/ and it seems to work as desired.

Comment: Or, `chart.onClick = function() {};`

Comment: is there a way to use this to center a particular selected element in a `dc.geoChoroplethChart` as in this example --> `smenglish.github.io/dash_snow`

Comment: I updated the fiddle to version 2.1.0 and the colors seemed fine to me.  See http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/3chM6/

Comment: @DJMartin the link shows fiddle with 1.7 not 2.1
Colors don't come for me either. Also, filtering is still working.

Comment: I updated this to be 2.1.  Not sure what you mean about the colors.  Filtering by clicking on the pie chart is disabled, as intended.  Filtering in the other direction is not disabled.

Comment: thanks @DJMartin for updating the version. If we don't override the filter function separately, it shows pieChart without colors. http://jsfiddle.net/erk3g05d/