# How do I turn the interactivity off with dc.js charts?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

given this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/hcfhds0a/1/)

**How do I turn the interactivity off with dc.js charts?**
For instance I don't want anything to happen when anywhere on the graph is clicked.

I would like to keep the on:hover option working, i.e. when you hover over the graph a label appears with the underlying value

i have tried `.turnOnControls(true)` but had no joy and also [.brushOn](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) :

```
    yearRingChart
        .width(200).height(200)
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .group(spendPerYear)
        .turnOnControls(true)
        .innerRadius(50);
```

**NOTE** Idon't seem to be very good at reading the [documentation](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) so any pointers here would be greatly appreciated.

---

### EDIT1

I have tried `.brushOn(false)` but I get `.brushOn is not a function` in the console. Maybe I am not using it right?

```
    yearRingChart
        .width(200).height(200)
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .group(spendPerYear)
        .brushOn(false) 
        .innerRadius(50);
```

---

### EDIT2

this is the answer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/hcfhds0a/13/), basically had to add this per chart `yearRingChart.filter = function() {};` taken from this duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783004/dc-js-disable-selecting-slices-on-click-for-pie-chart)

```
yearRingChart
    .width(200).height(200)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(spendPerYear)
    .innerRadius(50);
    yearRingChart.filter = function() {};
spenderRowChart
    .width(250).height(200)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .elasticX(true);
dc.renderAll();
spenderRowChart.filter = function() {};
```

Comment: Mostly [.brushOn(false)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+brushOn)

Comment: @Gordon tks but I have tried that and get `.brushOn is not a function` see edit1 above in question.

Comment: Good point that's a coordinate grid method. Maybe it should be available for all charts. How about a search on disable click dc.js pie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dc-js disable selecting slices on click for pie chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783004/dc-js-disable-selecting-slices-on-click-for-pie-chart)

Comment: @Gordon yes that was it see my edit2, how do i accept this or close it the option appears to be gone to colse it as a duplicate.tks

Comment: Not sure if you can vote to close your own question, anyway this will help folks who search on the terms in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT2

this is the answer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/hcfhds0a/13/), basically had to add this per chart `yearRingChart.filter = function() {};` taken from this duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783004/dc-js-disable-selecting-slices-on-click-for-pie-chart)

```
yearRingChart
    .width(200).height(200)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(spendPerYear)
    .innerRadius(50);
    yearRingChart.filter = function() {};
spenderRowChart
    .width(250).height(200)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .elasticX(true);
dc.renderAll();
spenderRowChart.filter = function() {};
```